# What types can Doctrines2's bindValue take?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a hard time navigating through Doctrine's Documentation for the DBAL. I would like to know what string values I can put in the $type value of this:

```
    bindValue($pointername, $variable, $type);
```

I did not find anything in the documentation that discusses the types.

I'm working with MySQL so I'd like to know the types I can put in the `bindValue` function that would equate to types like `varchar`, `tinyint`, `text`, `datetime`, `mediumtext`, `float`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/doctrine/dbal/statement.html#bindValue()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/doctrine/dbal/statement.html#bindValue%28%29) the `$type` parameter can be either a PDO type (see http://au.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) or a dbal mapping type (see http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/doctrine/dbal/types/type.html).

So you could use `PDO::PARAM_INT` or `Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::Integer` by the looks of things.